# background colour of floated boxes

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/) there's a `#container` div that has a white background. This white background doesn't appear behind the 5 floated boxes (with titles "Latest", Music Festivals, Alerts, etc.) even though those boxes are children of `#container` and don't specify a background colour of their own, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent container does not expand to fit floated elements. You need a way to "clear" the float to end the floating after the child elements. See this page:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 1):

you should add an `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after last floated element, so that your floated elements affect on increasing your `#container` block's height. otherwise they "fall out" from your container box.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [clear your floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) after using your `.box` class:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Here's the simplest way possible:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <br style="clear: both; display: block;" />
</div>
```